# Como eu faço um foreach dentro da View em uma ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Essas são as minhas ViewData na controller:

```
public ActionResult Acao()
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            var _listaUnidade  = Enumerable.Empty<object>();
            var _listaFamilia  = Enumerable.Empty<object>();
            var _listaProduto  = Enumerable.Empty<object>();
            var _listaCnpjDesc = Enumerable.Empty<object>();

            var monta_arvore = db.Ruptura
                               .Where(m => m.IDMotivo != 7)

                               .Select(rup => new MontaArvoreAcao
                               {
                                   IDRuptura = rup.IDRuptura,
                                   DataRuptura = rup.DataRuptura,
                                   IDMotivo = rup.IDMotivo,
                                   Motivo = rup.Motivo.Motivo1,
                                   IDOrigem = rup.IDOrigem,
                                   CodigoPDV = rup.CodigoPDV,
                                   UF = rup.PDV.UF,
                                   Cidade = rup.PDV.Cidade,
                                   CnpjDescricao = rup.PDV.Cnpj + " - " + rup.PDV.Descricao,
                                   Codigo_Apresentacao = rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
                                   Unidade_Negocio = rup.Apresentacao.Unidade_Negocio,
                                   Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = rup.Apresentacao.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
                                   Franquia = rup.Apresentacao.Franquia,
                                   Familia = rup.Apresentacao.Familia,
                                   Descricao = rup.Apresentacao.Descricao

                               }).ToList().OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo);

            foreach (var _idmotivo in monta_arvore)
            {
                _listaUnidade = db.Apresentacao
                                .Where(un => un.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio == _idmotivo.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio)
                                .Select(u => new MontaArvoreAcao
                                {
                                    Unidade_Negocio = u.Unidade_Negocio,
                                    Codigo_Familia = u.Codigo_Familia
                                }).ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Unidade_Negocio);
            }

            ViewData["ListaUn"] = _listaUnidade;

            foreach(var _idUn in monta_arvore)
            {
                _listaFamilia = db.Apresentacao
                                .Where(f => f.Codigo_Familia == _idUn.Codigo_Familia)
                                .Select(f => new MontaArvoreAcao
                                { 
                                    Familia = f.Familia,
                                    Codigo_Familia = f.Codigo_Familia
                                }).ToList();
            }

            ViewData["ListaFam"] = _listaFamilia;

            foreach(var _prod in monta_arvore)
            {
                _listaProduto = db.Apresentacao
                                .Where(p => p.Codigo_Apresentacao == _prod.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                .Select(prod => new MontaArvoreAcao
                                {
                                    Descricao = _prod.Descricao,
                                    Codigo_Apresentacao = _prod.Codigo_Apresentacao
                                }).ToList();
            }

            ViewData["ListaProd"] = _listaProduto;

            foreach(var cnpj in monta_arvore)
            {
                _listaCnpjDesc = db.PDV
                                 .Where(c => c.CodigoPDV == cnpj.CodigoPDV)
                                 .Select(x => new MontaArvoreAcao
                                 {
                                     CnpjDescricao = x.Cnpj + " - " + x.Descricao
                                 }).ToList();
            }

            return View(monta_arvore.ToList());
        }
```

Como eu faço agora na minha View o foreac para percorrê-la e preencher minha página. Abaixo minha View.

```
@{
                var _motivo = "";
                var _un = ViewData["ListaUn"];
                var _familia = "";
                var _desc = "";
                var _apr = "";

                int _idmotivo = 0;
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        if (_motivo != @item.Motivo)
                        {
                            _idmotivo = @item.IDMotivo;
                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                @item.Motivo
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach (var un in ViewData["ListaUn"])
                                    {
                                        <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                            @item.Unidade_Negocio

                                        </li>
                                        @*}*@
                                    }
                                </ul>
                              </li>

                            }
                            _motivo = @item.Motivo;
                        }
                </ul>
              }
```

O que passa é que nessa linha dá erro no tipo:

```
@foreach (var un in (System.Collections.Generic.List<Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao>ViewData["ListaUn"]))
```

Afinal, qual o tipo que eu carrego no List?

Eis o erro:

```
Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS0305: O uso de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' genérico requer argumentos de tipo 1
```

Na busca por fazer funcionar, fiz essa alteração e não deu mais nenhum erro, porém não trago mais nada na minha página, nem o Motivo que estava sendo carregado diretamente, sem ViewData ou ViewBag. Antes funcionava. O meu BD está devidamente populado, não é falta de registro. É problema mesmo. Fiz assim: Um include na página e mudança no foreach.

meu include:

```
@model IEnumerable<Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao>
```

meu foreach:

```
@foreach (var un in (ViewData["ListaUn"] as IEnumerable<Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao>))
```

Não entra no foreach. Coloquei um break e vi que não entra, ele pula direto.

Answer (score 3):

Experimenta:

```
foreach(var un in (List<Unidade>)ViewData["ListaUn"])
```

Comment: Então Miguel, esta tem sido minha dúvida. O que colocar no lugar de Unidade como você colocou. Qual o tipo, isso é que me levou ao post.

Comment: Onde tenho a Unidade é onde metes o teu tipo de dados da lista. Será Apresentacao??

Comment: Fiz umas edições para mostrar o progresso que venho atingindo, mas ainda não resolvi.

Answer (score 2):

O que o CesarMiguel respondeu está correto, porém o type para o List deve ser o último cast que você efetuou no controller, no caso **MontaArvoreAcao**

```
    foreach (var _idmotivo in monta_arvore)
        {
            _listaUnidade = db.Apresentacao
                            .Where(un => un.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio == _idmotivo.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio)
                            .Select(u => new MontaArvoreAcao
                            {
                                Unidade_Negocio = u.Unidade_Negocio,
                                Codigo_Familia = u.Codigo_Familia
                            }).ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Unidade_Negocio);
        }

        ViewData["ListaUn"] = _listaUnidade;
```

Sempre que você utilizar o Select() no Linq, será o type utilizado que sua query irá retornar. Nesse caso o Select() irá retornar um IEnumerable e como você utilizou o ToList(), irá retornar um

```
List<MontaArvoreAcao>
```